# proxy with perl script

Tags: perl, proxy

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use IO::Socket;

my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
   PeerAddr => 'remotehost',
   PeerPort => '1230',
   Proto => 'tcp',
 ) or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";


print "TCP Connection Success.\n";

# write on the socket to server.
$data = "this is the data to send";
$socket->send($data);


# read the socket data sent by server.
$data = <$socket>;
print "Received from Server : $data\n";

sleep(10);

close($sock);
```

I am unable to send and receive response from the remotehost using the above code...any ideas?

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 3):

You declared `my $sock` when you created the socket.  Then later you use

```
$socket->send($data)
```

This should be

```
$sock->send($data)
```

and later

```
$data = <$sock>
```

Comment: This should be `use strict; ...` *rest of script* `...`

Comment: yeah i realized that, but even after that i cannot get the server response printed out..

Comment: Is the server working correctly?  Did you change the `$socket` to `$sock` in the response line?  In my test I just ran `nc -l 127.0.0.1 1230`.  The perl script connected and sent its message, then I typed the reply in the `nc` window and the perl script received it.

Comment: the server is working correctly, when i do this from my java program it works fine...

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps try using the IP address of the host instead of the name?  This post has a little work-around if that is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160876/how-does-a-perl-socket-resolve-hostnames-under-linux

Answer (score 0):

When working with network data, it is useful to do this after declaring your socket:

`$sock->autoflush(1);`

By default your IO is buffered and most likely the `$data` variable is less than buffer size. In such a case OS is waiting for more data before sending full buffer to the remote host. Setting autoflush disables buffering.